# List of String in @RequestParam to Spring Controller

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

Currently I have Spring method that accepts tradeIds

**Spring Code**

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/tools/searchTrades"}, produces=APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, headers = "Content-Type=application/json", consumes=APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody SearchTradesVO searchTrades(
            @RequestParam(value = "tradeIds", required = true) final List<String> tradeIds) {


   }
```

**Jquery**
            Jquery ajax method to pass the  JSON of tradeIds to controller

```
        $("#searchTradeIds").validate({     
    rules: {
        tradeIds : {
            required: true,
            tradeIdFormat : true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        $.ajax({
            url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/etfadapter/tools/searchTrades",
            type : "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({tradeIds:["XXXXX10XX81", "XXXXX10XX82"]}),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',                    
            success : function(msg) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));                       
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Controller is expected to get the List tradeids. TradeIds are entered as comma seperated by user in a Text Area.

Chrome Developer console says -

```
POST http://localhost:8080/XXXXXXXXXX/etfadapter/tools/searchTrades 400 (Bad Request).
```

Guide me what is incorrect here.

Answer (score 0):

Json data is passed (POST) to controller in http body. Hence you should use @RequestBody instead of @RequestParam to receive your json message.